# Can't detect UIAlertView closing

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview

I got an app with an `UIAlertView`.

When this alertView close, i wanna implement some code. But i cant do it.

I connect `UIAlertViewDelegate` and the write this methods:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"%i",buttonIndex);
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"%i",buttonIndex);
}

-(void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    NSLog(@"cancel alert view");
}
```

But nothing typed in output. Why? Thnx.

UPD connection to UIAlertViewDelegate:

```
@interface PlaceListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you connected them?

Comment: Have you implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` in .h file? Also, did u set the delegate of the `UIAlertView`?

Comment: Can you also post the code where you show this `UIAlertView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those method calls look fine, so it's probably a problem with how you set up your delegate. Are you setting `delegate` to `self` when you create the alert view?

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ok"
             message:@"Do action?"
             delegate:self
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
             otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: forgot implement delegate:self =((( thnx